# Neighbor pattern look-up table enumeration on an octree mesh

Tags: algorithms

I am working with an octree mesh where variables are stored in a collocated fashion at octant centers. I want to construct a lookup table for interpolation weights that may occur using only a cell and it's immediately adjacent neighbor leaf cells. There are a specific number of neighbor configurations since each neighbor is only allowed to be 1 level coarser or finer than the cell for which an interpolation is required, and I want to specify a unique table id for each configuration. Figure 4 in the paper below shows pretty clearly what I mean by surrounding cell configuration.

http://www.math.uh.edu/~molshan/ftp/pub/OctreeMAC.pdf

Is there an algorithm/accepted way to enumerate these cases?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is too terse to really understand what it is you're looking for. That said, the paper that you should look at is this one by Burstedde et al.:
  http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/100791634
It describes the p4est library and has all sorts of algorithms to traverse octrees.

Comment: I edited my question. I hope this makes it clear what I am asking.